# Табы Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, tabs

Хочу сделать табы возник вопрос как мне сравнить индексы массивов двух классов чтобы по нужному клику выбирался нужный блок, тут я вписываю это вручную.

```js
var tabLink, tabContent;
    tabLink = document.getElementsByClassName('tab-link');
    tabContent = document.getElementsByClassName('tab-content');
for (var i=0;i<tabLink.length;i++) {
 switch(i) {
  case 0 : tabLink[i].onclick = function(){
   for(i=0; i<tabLink.length; i++){
    tabContent[i].classList.remove("active")
   }
   tabContent[0].classList.toggle("active")
  }
   break;
  case 1 : tabLink[i].onclick = function(){
   for(i=0; i<tabLink.length; i++){
    tabContent[i].classList.remove("active")
   }
   tabContent[1].classList.toggle("active")
  }
  break;
  case 2 : tabLink[i].onclick = function(){
   for(i=0; i<tabLink.length; i++){
    tabContent[i].classList.remove("active")
   }
   tabContent[2].classList.toggle("active")
  }
  break;
 }
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
 <title>CSS генератор</title>
</head>
<body>
 <style>
  .tab-content {
   display: none;
  }
  .active {
   display: block;
  }
 </style>
 <div>
  <a class="tab-link" href="#">TAB-1</a>
  <a class="tab-link" href="#">TAB-2</a>
  <a class="tab-link" href="#">TAB-3</a>
 </div>
 <div class="tab-content">
  <p>Блок 1
</p>
 </div>
 <div class="tab-content">
  <p>Блок 2
</p>
 </div>
 <div class="tab-content">
  <p>
Блок 3
</p>
 </div>
</body>
<script src="main.js"></script>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

А добавить уникальный ID для tab-link и tab-content для вашей задачи не подойдет?. [Примерно так](https://codepen.io/Lukyanenko/pen/OwXqPb?editors=1011)

```
var tabLink = document.getElementById('menu');
tabLink.addEventListener( "click" , function(ev) {
   var hideElement = document.getElementsByClassName('tab-content');
   for(i=0; i<hideElement.length; i++){
      hideElement[i].classList.remove("active")
   }
   var showElemtn = document.querySelectorAll('div#' + ev.target.id + '')[0];
   showElemtn.classList.toggle("active");
    });
```